# I Don't Know Why My If Statement Didn't Work (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, if-statement, rating

I have problem with my if statement, I try to display star base on average rating, for example if average 4.8 then should display warning star 4, but I have trying make statement only read first statement, the following is my condition code:

```
@if($reviews->average('rating') >= '3')
@for($i=1;$i<4;$i++)
    @php echo $i ? "<i class='mdi mdi-star me-n1 text-warning'></i>" : "<i class='mdi mdi-star me-n1 text-light'></i>"; @endphp
@endfor
@elseif($reviews->average('rating') >= '4')
@for($i=1;$i<5;$i++)
    @php echo $i ? "<i class='mdi mdi-star me-n1 text-warning'></i>" : "<i class='mdi mdi-star me-n1 text-light'></i>"; @endphp
@endfor
@endif
```

Please help me why my second statement didn't read, In this case the second statement should be read. Who anyone can help much appreciate.

Comment: If the average rating is 5 then both statements are true but only the first will work because it's before the  you are using an `elseif`. I think if you reverse the order of your conditions it should be fine (i.e. `>= 4` to come before `>= 3`)

Comment: because of using `else if`, you should use `if` instead of `else if`.

Comment: I have tried several conditions, and I try like you tell me too but still didn't work, I mean even I remove this part >= 4 or I order that part it's only read the first statement for a rating below 4, should be above because rating above four right now. But when I split the condition statement it's work, the problem both statements make star increase from 3 to 7 because they combine, so want or not I should make if else right?. So, do you have idea what wrong with this?, and as you know rating always change base on customer reviews. So that's why I really need that condition.

Comment: Ok i try like vahid tell.

Comment: Look weird, this case should be simple 'cause I have done more complicated cases, but in this lol. Not work yet bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comments the problem lays in the else if logic. You can use the review average directly in your for-loop if you adjust the comperator to `<=` instead of `<`. This makes the if statements somewhat obsolete.

```php
@for($i=1;$i <= $reviews->average('rating');$i++)
    @php echo $i ? "<i class='mdi mdi-star me-n1 text-warning'></i>" : "<i  class='mdi mdi-star me-n1 text-light'></i>"; @endphp
@endfor
```

In case the average is for example 4.5, the loop is going to execute 4 times. In case it is 3 it executes 3 times. In case of 3.5 it executes also 3 times.
You might need to add a functionality for partial stars or for rounding the number. Otherwise the displayed star rating and the actual rating might differ too much. For example, an average of 3.9 would be displayed as 3 but it would be more intuitiv to display 4 stars.

Comment: Oh no bro, this work as i want, thank u so much bro. This code so simple.